# How to align content of image inside div tailwindscss

Tags: javascript

This is the current output, as you can see the image inside the circle is not positioned to the center of the circle. `object-center` is not doing anything.

[image]

I tried

```
// Skill component
function Skill({ directionLeft }: Props) {
  return (
    {/* Outer div */}
    <div className='relative flex cursor-pointer group'>
    {/* Inner image */}
      <motion.img 
      className='object-center w-12 h-12 max-w-full border border-gray-500 rounded-full md:h-24 md:w-24 xl:w-32 xl:h-32 filter group-hover:grayscale'
      initial={{ x: directionLeft ? -200 : 200, opacity: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 1 }}
      whileInView={{ x: 0, opacity: 1}}
      src="typescript.png"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And these `<Skill />` components are used inside here

```
<div className='grid grid-cols-4 gap-5'>
  <Skill />
  <Skill />
</div>
```

**EDIT**

[First bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FQ8T.png)

Answer (score 1):

`object-position: center` is used to position elements that have adjusted with the `object-size` property.

> You can adjust how the replaced element's object's intrinsic size (that is, its natural size) is adjusted to fit within the element's box using the object-fit property. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position?retiredLocale=nl)

You'll want to center the `<img>` element from the parent with either Flexbox or Grid. I would recommend the latter using the `grid` and `place-items-center` Tailwind utility classes. [`place-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items) is a shorthand version of `align-items` and `justify-items`.

```
function Skill({ directionLeft }: Props) {
  return (
    {/* Outer div */}
    <div className='grid place-items-center relative cursor-pointer group'>
    {/* Inner image */}
      <motion.img 
      className='object-center w-12 h-12 max-w-full border border-gray-500 rounded-full md:h-24 md:w-24 xl:w-32 xl:h-32 filter group-hover:grayscale'
      initial={{ x: directionLeft ? -200 : 200, opacity: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 1 }}
      whileInView={{ x: 0, opacity: 1}}
      src="typescript.png"/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Still the results are the same..it didn't bring TS in the middle of the circle. See the post edit

Comment: You mean the actual letters TS? Because that wouldn't be centering but creating an offset as the image is actually centered. Are you sure you want that?

Comment: yeah, I want to center the letters

Comment: Then I would recommend using an image where the letters are in the center.